# How do I use .includes() or similar in a Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

I'm trying to check if the first arg includes the second on the following array of objects:

```
whatIsInAName(
[
 { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
 { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, 
 { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }
], 
{ last: "Capulet" });
```

I can't use `includes()` on my logic because it's an array method. I tried to retrieve the objects from the `whatIsInAName` and pass them into arrays using `Object.entries()`but that didn't worked too. My two options are to either "transform" the objects into arrays. Or find a different alternative to the `includes()` method, that i'm able to use in an object.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Use`some` method to check whether `Capulet` exists in an array:

```
let obj = { last: "Capulet" };
const isExist = whatIsInAName.some(f => f.last == obj.last)
```

```js
const whatIsInAName = [
  { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
  { first: "Mercutio", last: null },
  { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }
 ];

let obj = { last: "Capulet" };
const isExist = whatIsInAName.some(f => f.last == obj.last)
console.log(`Exists: ${isExist}`)
```

Or you can use `filter` to get all objects based on criteria:

```js
const whatIsInAName = [
  { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
  { first: "Mercutio", last: null },
  { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }
 ];

let obj = { last: "Capulet" };
const result = whatIsInAName.filter(f => f.last == obj.last);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think the filter alternative should be removed

Comment: @Ele Thanks for the comment. I've moved `filter` code lower. Let's wait to know what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do a custom `includes` using `some` which will be faster than a `map`/`filter`

```js
function whatIsInAName(arr, obj) {
  return arr.some(({
    last
  }) => last === obj.last)
}

const testArray = [{
    first: "Romeo",
    last: "Montague"
  },
  {
    first: "Mercutio",
    last: null
  },
  {
    first: "Tybalt",
    last: "Capulet"
  }
]

const testObj1 = {
  last: "Capulet"
}
const testObj2 = {
  last: "FOO"
}

const res1 = whatIsInAName(testArray, testObj1);
const res2 = whatIsInAName(testArray, testObj2);

console.log(res1);
console.log(res2);
```